# SVM training runs endlessly depending on the configuration of the training dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I am currently facing a rather strange situation for which I don't have an answer. I need to create a classifier in Python using the scikit packages. For instance, I'm using Sklearn V.0.23.1 and Python V 3.6.9. My code is the following:

```
    def train_model(doTrain, xtrain, ytrain, xtest, ytest, filename, descriptors): 
 
        #The x_train docs contain the descriptors: feature1, feature2, feature3, feature4, feature5
        #The y_train docs contain the class of the region (0, 1)
        classifier = c.Pixel_Classifier

        x_train = np.array(classifier.json_open(xtrain))
        y_train = np.array(classifier.json_open(ytrain))
        x_test = np.array(classifier.json_open(xtest))
        y_test = np.array(classifier.json_open(ytest))

        x_train = x_train[:, 0:descriptors]
        x_test = x_test[:, 0:descriptors]

        if doTrain == True:
            clf = svm.SVC(kernel = 'poly', degree = 2, gamma = 'auto')
            clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
            # save the model to disk 
            joblib.dump(clf, filename) 
 
        return(x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test, filename)

    # Loads the model we have calculated previously and obtains the Fscore fore the desired dataset
    def load_model_and_fscore (filename, dataset_x, dataset_y):

        # load the model from disk 
        loaded_model = joblib.load(filename) 
        result = loaded_model.score(dataset_x, dataset_y)
        print("The obtained Fscore is: ",result)
```

The code where I call these functions is the following:

```
def main():
    descriptors = 3
    doTrain = True
    
    qsvm = q.Quadratic_Svm
    t = time.time()
    # Switch the variable doTrain between True or False if you desire to train a new model or not, else it will just load the data
    (x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test, filename) = qsvm.train_model (doTrain, 'x_train_5', 'y_train_5', 'x_test_5', 'y_test_5', 'quadratic_svm_3pred.sav', descriptors)
    elapsed_time = time.time() - t
    print("TOTAL TIME: ",elapsed_time)
    #For 5 descriptors --> 100.18249130249023
    #For 4 descriptors --> 179.14637875556946
    #For 3 descriptors --> NaN
    #For 2 descriptors --> NaN

    # Load the model and calculate the fscores
    qsvm.load_model_and_fscore(filename, x_train, y_train)

if __name__ == __main__:
    main()
```

The main problem is that my dataset consists of 5 columns and 66 rows, and when I run that I am able to obtain the model, however I do not want to have 5 columns and instead I have chopped the dataset so it has only the first 3 columns. When trying to fit the model for the 3 columns dataset the program runs endlessly and to be exact it gets stuck here `clf.fit(x_train, y_train)`, where x_train is the 66x3 matrix and y_train is a 66x1 matrix of ones and zeros containing the class to be classified.

To add some more background, the classifier must be a quadratic SVM as I am trying to replicate a model that has been previously obtained in MATLAB.

I don't have much experience programming, nor I have done any project before using skelearn, so it baffles me that the same program is able to finish with a larger dataset but it is unable to do so with a smaller one, which keeps me wondering if it may be a problem of the classifier needing a minimum number of input data to be able to work.

Thanks in advance, and in case of more information being required just let me know.

EDIT: I have included the main where I call these functions and a piece of the dataset is listed below:

x_train_5.json (since it is too large to copy & paste I just add the 10 first rows, although I do not know if it is possible to paste the whole file)

[
[
559,
0.831001944835049,
0.4014244151599471,
0.4275322391706655,
3.530239088136949
],
[
546,
0.8500745647876297,
0.9604186417971177,
0.46119129075599014,
4.896232517640669
],
[
1666,
0.34977439775327673,
0.8903153074172299,
0.44679984549906065,
4.691513630875018
],
[
4835,
0.19188968136372858,
0.9873278899326821,
-1.1923195893000236,
3.374447074416752
],
[
1395,
0.45667718897610743,
0.46077762831666325,
0.8382348234046015,
4.459961261557849
],
[
779,
0.17748260160439014,
0.9799190582592539,
1.3968968004261724,
2.7886021727364856
],
[
1542,
0.3349879307279103,
0.9645625988326306,
1.409321071776312,
2.7592245282780494
],
[
299,
0.6853763332627717,
0.3536264838352429,
1.4961251102387,
4.276223175418815
],
[
15921,
0.10671363787703753,
0.8755112566971346,
-1.541062009534888,
3.3918151659142777
],
[
2708,
0.12767863888034417,
0.8273051900733546,
1.4878341577752447,
3.6409980309794885
],
... ]

and y_train_5.json

[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1,...]

Comment: please add some example data and the code where you call this function. As you have said the code seems to run, so there is probably some problem with the input/preprocessing.

Comment: I could not find a way to add the jsons that I use however I posted a few rows. Let me know if that works or if you need more. To add on the issue, it seems that if I chop the dataset down to 4 columns the program ends perfectly however it takes longer to compute the classifier, which to me seems counterintuitive.

Comment: Whichever was the fault, it seems the problem is related to the gamma used. As gamma is 1/n_features, in this case 3, it seems there might be some kind of problem because aproximating said gamma by 0.333 is the maximum iI can approach without getting stuck.